# Deleting through pointers inside functions

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider

```
void d(int* t) { //pointer passed by value
    delete t;
    std::cout << *t << '\n';
}
```

and

```
void d2(int*& t) { //pointer passed by reference
    delete t;
    std::cout << *t << '\n';
}
```

Say we have:

```
int *y = new int{22};
d(y);
d2(y);
```

- In the first case (d(y)), my understanding is a copy of a pointer is created.
- In the second case, my understanding is I passed it by reference, so still one pointer points to y

In both cases, I expected:

```
std::cout << *t << '\n';
```

to cause undefined behavior because I should have deleted the value of t. But I can still dereference it successfully, as if "delete t;" did nothing. Why is that?

Comment: What do you think "UB" means?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Haha, good one!

Comment: Okay, it means undefined behavior. But what do you think undefined behavior means?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/1382251), although it refers to accessing a local variable's memory outside of its scope (which is technically different from what you're asking), provides an an equally good answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "cause UB" / "But I can still dereference it successfully, as if "delete t;" did nothing. Why is that?"

"successfully" as in it may compile, but not "succesfully" as in "don't have to worry about the UB".  Why?  Because the compiler's not attempting (or expected) to model your runtime program state during compilation: it's your job to make sure your program won't attempt something with undefined behaviour at runtime.

> In the second case, my understanding is I passed it by reference, so still one pointer points to y

No... you don't have any pointers to `y`... you have a reference to `y`.  Anyway, the `int`s don't exist after `delete t`, and it's the other way around: when you copy the pointer - calling `d()` not `d2()`, the caller's copy of `y` is unaffected and becomes a dangling pointer to where the `int`s used to be (which is totally useless).  Further, if `d(y);` is called then `d2(y);` has undefined behaviour at the `delete t;` statement, not just `*t`.

Comment: `y` exists, but `*y` does not.

Comment: @BenVoigt: true... the "one pointer points to y" part of the question made me start thinking of y as the pointed-to data for some reason.  Anyway, reworded/corrected.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I tested this with std::string and finally it crashed!